# Using SMW subobjects without having to duplicate the content

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

### Example for what I want to achieve

I have many patch pages ("Patch 1.4", "Patch 1.5" etc.) that list the changes that were made to a project, where the affected/changed things are linked to their corresponding pages ("confirmation dialog", "foo", etc.):

> **Patch 1.4**
>
> - Fixed spelling in the [[confirmation dialog]]

> **Patch 1.5**
>
> - Added two options: [[foo]], [[bar]]

On the pages about the things that were changed ("confirmation dialog", "foo", …), I want to automatically show all corresponding changes:

> **Foo**
>
> - [[Patch 1.5]]: Added two options: [[foo]], [[bar]]

### Semantic MediaWiki’s *subobjects* can do this

[`#subobject`](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Adding_subobjects) allows me to create an (anonymous) object for each change on the patch pages:

```
{{#subobject:|
|Changes=Added two options: [[foo]], [[bar]]
|Affects=Foo|Bar
}}
```

And on each page ("foo" etc.) I can include an [`#ask` subobject query](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Subobjects_and_queries) to list all the matching subobjects:

```
{{#ask: [[Affects::{{FULLPAGENAME}}]]
 |? Changes
}}
```

Great.

### Problem: I have to duplicate the change entry.

On the patch pages, a change entry looks like this:

```
* Added two options: [[foo]], [[bar]] {{#subobject:|
|Changes=Added two options: [[foo]], [[bar]]
|Affects=Foo|Bar
}}
```

So I have to specify "Added two options: [[foo]], [[bar]]" two times: one time for the visible content, one time for the invisible subobject.

**Is there a way in (Semantic) MediaWiki to do this without having to duplicate the content?**

The ideal solution would just require me to enclose the change entry and specify the affected pages next to it, e.g.:

```
* {{ Added two options: [[foo]], [[bar]] }}((foo|bar))
```

As each patch page can list hundreds of changes, I don’t want to have to create a separate page for each change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question clearly, it seems you just need a simple query:

```
{{#ask: [[-Has subobject::{{FULLPAGENAME}}]] 
| ?Changes
| format = ul
| headers = hide
| mainlabel = -
}}
```

Since using SMW markup may be tedious and error-prone, you might also use MediaWiki templates. You can simplify adding patch changes:

**Template:Change**

```
<includeonly><!--
-->{{#subobject:|
   | Changes = {{{1|}}}
   | Affects = {{{2|}}}|+sep=;
   }}<!--
--></includeonly><nowiki/>
```

`{{{1}}}` and `{{{2}}}` are positional parameter,s and the `Affects` subobject property uses the `;` separator (as a pipe `|` is ambiguous and may break templates, parser functions, etc). The `<nowiki/>` is a sort of a hack saving from whitespace bloating at the call-site pages.

You can also add a special template that would encapsulate the changes query:

**Template:Patch changes**

```
<includeonly><!--
-->{{#ask: [[-Has subobject::{{{1|{{FULLPAGENAME}}}}}]] 
   | ?Changes
   | format = ul
   | headers = hide
   | mainlabel = -
   }}<!--
--></includeonly><nowiki/>
```

By default, the template asks for the changes list for the current page (if the positional parameter #1 argument is empty), or you can explicitly override it at the call-site later (say, `{{Patch changes|Patch 1.5}}`).

**Patch 1.4**

```
{{Change | Fixed spelling in the [[confirmation dialog]] | Confirmation dialog}}

{{Patch changes}}
```

**Patch 1.5**

```
{{Change | Added two options: [[foo]], [[bar]] | Foo; Bar}}

{{Patch changes}}
```

respectively.

These links might be useful later:

- [SMW subobjects and queries](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Subobjects_and_queries)
- [SMW standard parameters for inline queries](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Inline_queries#Standard_parameters_for_inline_queries)
- [SMW templates](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Semantic_templates)
- [MW templates anonymous parameters](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Templates#Anonymous_parameters)

Comment: Nice solution, thank you! It didn’t occur to me to query for the subobjects on the same page. The only caveat I can see: I lose the individual structure (headings, nested lists, etc.) of the original patch notes. I guess headings could be reproduced by adding another property and inserting a separate query for each heading, but that would of course be more work when marking it up.

Comment: Oh, I think I could simply add the `{{{1|}}}` a second time in the template (outside of the `#subobject`)! This way the template creates both: the visible content as well as the hidden subobject. And I wouldn’t have to query for the subobjects on the patch pages, so the structure (with headings etc.) can be kept.

Comment: @unor yes, I was thinking of such an approach too, but I didn't consider more advanced structuring for a particular case, and I almost always try to keep "data" and "report" templates designed apart, so each of them could have their own responsibilities. Sure, it makes the templates and data structure more complicated (true design; additionally SMW is also a complicated tool itself as well), but I think your suggested solution is really good for your case. Templates can make great job. :)